# One query for each request or one query for all requests?

Tags: asp.net, database, terminology

I honestly don't know if I'm asking something very obvious, that you just look and say: Obviously one query per request it's better!

But here we go...

**The application**

We're talking about an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 app, like a Dashboard. I'd say that it's a small/medium application, using Oracle database.

**Scenario**

I need to do N querys to show N indicators... But I can filter this values on memory or directly on database.. I need a result like this:

```
ID         Value         Type

1          25560.00      1
2          2330.00       1
3          140.00        2
4          10.00         1
5          50.00         3
6          40.00         3
7          33.00         1
```

In the end my requests would be like:

1. Show me a percent (I have a formula for that) of all IDs which has Type = 1
2. Show me a percent (I have a formula for that) of all IDs which has Type = 2
3. Show me a percent (I have a formula for that) of all IDs which has Type = 3

**My question**

Which one is better?

1. Put all my data inside my ViewBag and filter everything using JS?
2. Consolidate the info on database, doing one query for each request?

Comment: I usually create a view on the backend (DB) maybe with subviews and then send the result to the client side. But maybe that is old school (from the days that transferring the data and client memory/processing was expensive).

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion:

it depends, if the database query require more effort, for example to query a large database, then optimize on database side is the best option, it reduces the database load.

if the database query is light, then it is better to send all data to the client and filter client side, reducing http request and latency.